# Selecting into class related data only when it exists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have A 'states' table and related 'status' table. 'State' can have 0 or 1 'status'. Currently I query it like this:

```
IQueryable<State> statesRecords = getStates();

var result = statesRecords
    .Select(st => new StateModel()
    {
        HardwareId = st.HardwareId,
        StateId = st.StateId,
        Status = st.Status != null ? new StatusModel() // check whether related status exists
        {
            Comment = st.Status.Comment,
            TimeStamp = st.Status.TimeStamp
        }:null,
        TimeStamp = st.TimeStamp
    }).OrderByDescending(r => r.TimeStamp).ToList();
```

Is it a proper way, or there's any more elegant one?

Comment: Why you don't use something like automapper for mapping automatically. Than you don't have to think about creating a model. http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html

Comment: @nzrytmn I want to do it only by means of entity framework

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. It will be useful if you share a bit more information. Something like your table's structure.  At the moment I  can say it is better you make a filter with status before select.

Comment: @nzrytmn Please, take a look at my code. The question is is it possible to avoid using the ternary operator where I check related 'status' for existance.